# Failed to obtain a cell from its DataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What is wrong with the below code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";

    return cell;
}
```

And

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 2;
}
```

but I'm getting **failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource**

The entire exception is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7ffe0b092800; frame = (0 97; 414 590); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ffe0acf3b10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffe0aceb6e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 88}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<AllContactsViewController: 0x7ffe0ace60f0>)'
```

I have set delegate and data source for the table view

Comment: Have you registered that reuse identifier (in your storyboard?). If not then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` may return nil and it is then your responsibility to allocate a new cell and return that

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Your error suggests that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning `nil` for some reason, and I'm guessing it's because you are failing to dequeue a reusable cell. If you want to confirm this, just set a breakpoint after your current dequeue call: I expect you'll find `cell` is set to `nil`.

If you're using modern Xcode templates where you get a prototype cell made for you, you should probably be using this instead:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If you aren't using an Xcode template, use that line of code anyway then register your own re-use identifier like this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

All being well that should resolve the problem. [I wrote this up in more detail for Swift users.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/fixing-failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource)

Comment: OK I'm so bad at ios now. The registration thing worked. I am using the latest xcode but the tutorials are old. Guess I need to learn more as I have no idea where did this  registration thing came from. So we need to register the tableVIew object in order to use it if we are not using the prototype cell. Right?

Comment: Everyone starts bad at first; you are trying, asking questions, and learning – great job! My own iOS tutorials are up to date, [so you might want to try them](https://www.hackingwithswift.com). In answer to your question: you don't register the table view object, you register the cell type you want to use. That way, when the table view tries to pull one out it knows what you mean.

Comment: Got it. But your tutorial is in swift, I needed Objective C.

Comment: Yes your rite. I have used multiple tableview inside the view controller and I forgot to return one Cell.  Thank You...,

Answer (score 148):

Using Swift 3 I encountered this error when I forgot to add the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols to the ViewController declaration.

class DataViewController: UIViewController, **UITableViewDataSource**, **UITableViewDelegate**

Adding them fixed the problem.

Comment: Seems a bug in Swift 3?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if Apple would call this a "bug" or a "feature".  After verifying the behavior described by David Reidy, I filed a bug, 29314493.    I said that either it should "just work without the protocol declaration" (which is what I would expect in Objective-C), or maybe because Swift is supposed to be more fussy, an exception indicating that "Data source <whatever> of UITableView <whatever> does not declare itself as conforming to UITableViewDataSource", instead of the very misleading exception described in this question.

Comment: Same for Objective C

Comment: And moreover, if you dont add protocol conformance, tableview calls numberOfRowsInSection normaly, but crashes before calling to cellForRowAt indexPath. There is no any logic sadly

Answer (score 43):

## Swift 3.0

You just need to add **UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSource**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

#### Below image is just for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Image is just for knowledge,copy UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource from above with bold letters :)

Comment: Strange, I always used to connect the UITableView delegates/datasource via IBOutlet, it used to work fine. Anyways thanks for this

Comment: @anoop4real It's fine to add the delegate/datasource, but it won't work without this step, as it is adding the protocols

Comment: @TheLastSummer Thank you for answer, but still I have not effect in my profile.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the cell an identifier. "Cell" give to the identifier of cell as in the attributes inspector of cell in the identifier field.
I re-produced your error and it is due to you have not given an identifier to your cell.

Comment: I used a table view on a view controller. I don't see any identifier field in the attribute inspector when I click on table view. Maybe because I have not used a cell upon my table view?

Comment: In tableView you have to select dynamic prototypes and create a cell by incrementing the count just below it. Then a cell will be added.You can select any pre-defined or custom cell type.In this cell you have to give an cell identifier in the attribute inspectors of cell.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was because I forgot to implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols

just add them to your class declaration after the inherited class

xcode must warn me about that, because I used UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods in my code

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was forgot to declare UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate for UITableview.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I forgot to change from dynamic prototype to static cell, check this part in your interface builder

Answer (score 2):

***Careful when you are migrating***
In case anyone is migrating their code from older swift versions to newer ones,  this may occur if you unintentionally don't change `UITableViewDataSource` functions' syntax to the newer swift syntax.
Unfortunately the compiler won't complain about it.
I faced this when I was migrating my code from swift 2 to swift 4. I didn't change cellForRow DataSource method syntax from:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

to its swift 4 version:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and I got the error:

```
"Failed to obtain a cell from its DataSource"
```

Comment: Save my time bro (Y)
Nice finding.

Answer (score 1):

Also please try the below code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    // Reuse and create cell    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Update cell data contents
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Your text here";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Your detailed text label";

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After having done the steps suggested in the other posts, and checking if my cell was nil, it my problem was not resolved and my cell was *not* showing as nil when I checked it.  However, adding this handy code snippet in there did resolve the issue, so it must have been nil at some point where I wasn't catching it.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClassNameOfMyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if have added UITableViewDataSource were added. I missed this, so that app was crashing

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not forgotten to implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Protocols.

`class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using the same Identifier you have given in the main story board for prototype cell. Try to telly the name for Upper case lower case as well to make sure you are using correct identifier.

Good Luck:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not loading Nib then you have to first register Nib in viewDidLoad.

```
 [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecruitmentDetailViewC" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RecruitmentDetailViewC"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When using tableViewCell apart from the UITableView you have to register
the NIB yourself. When the NIB is not registered the "Failed to obtain a cell from its DataSource" error may occur. 
From the error description I always find it hard to figure out, what is wrong.

This error can easily be solved by registering:

```
 [self registerNib:[customerButtonTableViewCell class]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:customerButtonCellIdentifier forTableView:tableView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override 'cellForRowAt' method. Take care if you didn't do it

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old already, but for my end, the problem was that the cell isn't part of the target membership.

So the fix I did was to include it in the target membership.