# Searchbar cause app to crash in my ios library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, dylib

I'm working on an external dynamic cocoa library (dylib) that at some point provides a view with a tableview and a search bar.
I have this on the on create

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:CONTACT_CELL bundle:frameworkBundle];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL];
    [self readContacts];
}
```

and for my tablerow delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell was empty!");
    }

    Contact *c = [contacts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell labelName] setText: [c getName]];
    [[cell labelPhone] setText: [c getPhone]];

    return cell;
}
```

problem is that when i click on the searchbar the app chrashes because:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView
>   _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:7962
>   2016-02-19 17:07:00.404 HostApp[2233:20181] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 528}>)
>   failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'

---

if I use

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL forIndexPath: indexPath];
```

> *** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:6564
>   2016-02-19 17:37:08.254 HostApp[2691:28849] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable
>   to dequeue a cell with identifier ContactCell - must register a nib or
>   a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a
>   storyboard'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250595/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource ?

Comment: i tried to put `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL]` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I registered the nib for the "normal" tableView, but not for the searchdisplaycontroller's tableView.

Using this viewDidLoad will fix the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:CONTACT_CELL bundle:frameworkBundle];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView  registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL];
    [self readContacts];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `nil` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You can either use :

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL forIndexPath: indexPath];
```

Which always returns a cell, or manually alloc it :

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CONTACT_CELL];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell was empty!");
        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:<#(UITableViewCellStyle)#> reuseIdentifier:<#(nullable NSString *)#>];
    }

    Contact *c = [contacts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell labelName] setText: [c getName]];
    [[cell labelPhone] setText: [c getPhone]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:CONTACT_CELL bundle:frameworkBundle];` in your viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Not null. I had to implement that way because the custom cell xib wouldn't load like the everiday's way i do it (because I'm implementing an external library).

Comment: and your nib's only view is a `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: pardon? I have a xib with tableview and searchbar, and another xib for the cell. The app crash when I type something in the search bar

Answer (score 0):

check 
1.search bar delegate for what you return 
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{}
2. check number of rows in section tableview deleage

Answer (score 0):

Try like  this

`ItemCell` is my nibName not an identifier

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ItemCell" bundle:nil];
     [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
           // Create an instance of ItemCell
   PointsItemCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your viewDidLoad don't work for me, since I'm coding inside my framework and not my main app (bundle: nil don't work).