# Swift xcode project error. Cannot retrieve cell from table

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

EDIT:
I can't find that method inside the AppDelegate class. Where is it? Do I just make one up?

My project is to build an app that has a list of animals' names inside one window, then when you click a row, you get transported to another window with a description of the animal.

When it crashes I get this message (see screenshot):

[image]

Here is all my storyboard, with links, and all my classes (and code within them)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The navigation bar doesn't have anything in the Connections Inspector (arrow tab) on the right.

Comment: Please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code as that's where the problem is.

Comment: I can't find that method inside the AppDelegate class. Where is it? Do I just make one up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be because your returning nil from you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source delegate method.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250654/1305067

Comment: I can't find the method named "cellForRowAtIndexPath" inside the AppDelegate class should I just make one up?

Comment: Yes, it's a required method that you need to implement for table views to work. I suggest you look at a simple table view tutorial such as (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) that explains how to get a basic table view up and running.

Answer (score 0):

When you forgot to add the **UITableViewDataSource** and **UITableViewDelegate** protocols to the ViewController declaration.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

You need to just copy and paste above code them fixed the problem.

But you make sure you should implement protocol method in your **DetailViewController**