# Swift 3 - Table View failed to obtain cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Im getting the following error:

> 2016-06-22 20:36:42.343016 Fibre[589:131756] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3575.10/UITableView.m:7964
>   2016-06-22 20:36:42.345150 Fibre[589:131756] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {383, 280}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x184989980 0x183f844bc 0x184989854 0x1853adc84 0x18a85465c 0x18aa522bc 0x18aa523c0 0x18aa40924 0x18aa57084 0x18a7f740c 0x18a71058c 0x187c34d6c 0x187c29aac 0x187c2996c 0x187ba94fc 0x187bd07c4 0x187bd1148 0x184939954 0x184937584 0x184937a14 0x18486a2e4 0x18624315c 0x18a77e6fc 0x18a779438 0x100070c3c 0x18440c600)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

from the following code:

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import UIKit


extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main()) {
            (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let imageData = data as Data? {
                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
    }
}
}

class offersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {




@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



@IBOutlet weak var offersView: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var offerTitleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var smartCode: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var customerName: UILabel!


@IBAction func closeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    offersView.isHidden = true
}



var array: [String] = [String]()
var arrayImages: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()




}


 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.array.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    self.arrayImages.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    print(weekDay)

    tableView.isHidden = true




    let query = PFQuery(className:"offers")
    query.whereKey("day", equalTo:"\(weekDay)")



    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {


                let birthdayOffer = "£25 free credit on your Birthday!"
                let birthdayOfferImage = "birthday"

                self.array.append(birthdayOffer as String)
                print(self.array)

                self.arrayImages.append(birthdayOfferImage as String)
                print(self.arrayImages)


                for object in objects {



                    let query = PFQuery(className:"offers")
                    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "\(object.objectId!)"){
                        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
                            let offertitle = gameScore!["offertitle"] as! String
                            let offerImage = gameScore!["imagename"] as! String

                            // Add birthday to array



                            self.array.append(offertitle as String)
                            print(self.array)

                            self.arrayImages.append(offerImage as String)
                            print(self.arrayImages)


                        }



                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.isHidden = false
                    }



                }


            }


        }



    }








    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {


    return false

  }






   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return array.count


    }

var cell : UITableViewCell?

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell: TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath) as! TblCell


        let url = URL(string: "https://checkmyweave.co.uk/\(arrayImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]).png")
        cell.offerImage.sd_setImage(with: url)




               cell.offerTitleLabel.text = self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard()






        let userID = defaults.string(forKey: "userID")!



        let query = PFQuery(className:"members")
        query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "\(userID)") {
            (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && gameScore != nil {

                let smartCode = gameScore!["smartcode"] as! String

                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard()




                let userName = defaults.string(forKey: "userName")!

        self.smartCode.text = smartCode
        self.customerName.text = userName




            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }


        return cell




  }




 func numberOfSections(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)


    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    offerTitleLabel.text = self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


    offersView.isHidden = false
    print(offerTitleLabel.text)
    let query = PFQuery(className:"offers")
    query.whereKey("offertitle", equalTo:"\(offerTitleLabel.text!)")
    query.whereKey("day", equalTo:"\(weekDay)")

    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {



                    let query = PFQuery(className:"offers")
                    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "\(object.objectId!)"){
                        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
                            let offerdesc = gameScore!["offerDesc"] as! String

                            print(offerdesc)




                        }}}}}}
   }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}



}
```

Can anyone explain why?

thanks!

Comment: Why do you have an instance of ```UITableViewCell``` named ```cell```as a  local variable in ```offersViewController``` ?

Comment: I think you forgot UITableViewDataSource  protocol. Perfect solution for you, Just open this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/41566649/5514539