# NSInternalInconsistencyException when customize tableview cell in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want use storyboard to create custom `UITableViewCell`, and when I run my program, it crashed, here is the log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; animations = { position=; }; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 304.23076923076923}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'

and I just get my tableviewcell using its identifier:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ThemeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"themecell"];

    return cell;
}
```

Here are some constraints in my storyboard:

[constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpk71.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250595/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource ?

Comment: make sure you have ThemeCell register with your cell in storyboard , and have correct identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) make sure you are using the correct tableviewcell identifier.
2) Then, do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ThemeCell *cell = (ThemeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"themecell"];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Storyboard`, make sure that you set `UITableViewCell` identifier in this tab

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just make a mistake that I regard the identifier as restoration identifier.