# UITableview: failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I get this error message: `failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource`

The strange that

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

not even get called, problem is not that returned cell is nil. I put in  breakpoints. `cellForRowAt`not get called.

`numberOfRowsInSection` returns value.

I do not know it is relating or not, but now I do not use `UITableViewController`, I just have a `UIViewController`, and it is the `datasource` and `delegate` for the `UITableView`. I hope it can not cause interfere. Any idea?

Comment: Any Errors sss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross check below check list:-

- it's because you are failing to dequeue a reusable cell.

  - The problem is that your cellForRowAtIndexPath function is embedded in another function
  - when you forgot to add the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols to the `ViewController declaration`.

class DataViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Right, I forget protocols

Comment: How to deal with the `does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is your problem - [Failed to obtain a cell from its DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250595/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource)

you can take a look at: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/fixing-failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource

try something like this:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(getCellIdentifierForType(cellType))
        setDataToCell(cell, item: item)
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure when you are migrating your code from swift older to new versions then your tableview data source and delegates have updated syntax.
For example

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

Can not auto updated to below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```