# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) by appDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have very limited knowledge in swift 3. My code compiles but app crashes upon launch with the following error. I have know clue what is going on or how to fix it. An help would be appreciated.

```
2017-02-14 15:34:58.535 Application[23749:1525292] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UITableView.m:8035
2017-02-14 15:34:58.538 Application[23749:1525292] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 264}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ff934b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102ed821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ffd442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000102a6ee4d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000103925bfe -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 222
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010393181c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 860
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103931a13 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010390547d -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010393ad95 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001039215ef -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103888f50 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108dc5cc4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108db9788 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108db9606 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108d47680 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108d74767 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108d750d7 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f9de17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f9dd87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f824b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001037be7e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001037c4964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  Application                         0x00000001028efb6f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106f2668d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please try [searching on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+failed+to+obtain+a+cell+from+its+dataSource).

Comment: Please look here for your answer: [UITableView Configure Cell For Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311201/assertion-failure-in-uitableview-configurecellfordisplayforindexpath)

Comment: You can find reasons in this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39902730/3507433 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/40158321/3507433 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/34250654/3507433

Comment: I think the main reason that you doesn't register cell for your table view. If not please check if reuse identifiers for registered and dequeued cells are the same.