# SIGABRT failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sigabrt

I have done extensive research on this issue, and I have tried everything in the book, but nothing works. Can someone please help? Below is the error and the code. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
**Code**

//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  Photos 2
//
//  Created by Cameron on 1/17/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Cameron. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
//, UISearchResultsUpdating

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating{


    @IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!


    var photosArray = [Photo]()
    var filteredPhotos = [Photo]()

    var searchController:UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("Load")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Load2")


        self.photosArray += [Photo(name: "One")]

        print("Load3")

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        TableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        definesPresentationContext = true

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        print("Load4")

        self.TableView.reloadData()
        print("Load5")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        print("updatesearchresults")
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchText!)
        TableView.reloadData()
        print("updatesearchresultsdone")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("numberofsections")
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("TableView")
        if(searchController.isActive){
            print("TableViewFinishedFiltered")
            return self.filteredPhotos.count
        } else {
            print("TableViewFinishedNormal")
            return self.photosArray.count
        }


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        print("TableView2")
        let cell = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        TableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        var photo: Photo
        if(searchController.isActive){
            photo = self.filteredPhotos[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            photo = self.photosArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.textLabel!.text = photo.name
        print(photo.name)
        print("TableView2Finished")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Why is this being acessed")
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        var photo: Photo
        if(searchController.isActive){
            photo = self.filteredPhotos[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            photo  = self.photosArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        //Load the photo based off the name
        print(photo.name)


    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "Title"){
        print("FilterContent")
        self.filteredPhotos = self.photosArray.filter({(photo: Photo) -> Bool in

            var categoryMatch = (scope == "Title")
            var stringMatch = photo.name.range(of: searchText)
            print("FilterContentDone")
            return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)

        })


    }

    func searchDisplayController(_ controller: UISearchController, shouldReloadTableForSearch searchString: String?) -> Bool {
        print("SearchDisplayController")
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchString!, scope: "Title")
        print("SearchDisplayControllerDone")
        return true
    }

    func searchDisplayController(_ controller: UISearchController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
        print("SearchDisplayController2")
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchText: (self.searchController!.searchBar.text)!, scope: "Title")
        print("SearchDisplayController2Done")
        return true

    }

}

**Console Output**
Load
Load2
Load3
TableView
TableViewFinishedNormal
Load4
TableView
TableViewFinishedNormal
Load5
TableView
TableViewFinishedNormal
TableView
TableViewFinishedNormal
TableView
TableViewFinishedNormal
2017-02-10 10:04:41.644 Photos 2[45848:651521] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:8042
2017-02-10 10:04:41.652 Photos 2[45848:651521] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7ffa99069000; frame = (0 20; 320 499); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000004c4b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000226080>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 430}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<Photos_2.SecondViewController: 0x7ffa96407b80>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001100fed4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d41121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110102e42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010cfa666d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010da429cd -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 222
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010da4e5eb -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 860
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010da4e7e2 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010da222b0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010da57b64 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010da3e3be -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d9a5ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112f44bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112f38440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d993928 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1509
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010dac38b1 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1625
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010dac26df -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 341
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010dabfa25 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 921
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010dda5ad8 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 418
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010dda5e3a -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 766
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d96dbd5 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 222
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010d9697d2 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 307
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010dda584e -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 2808
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010dac495b -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3314
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010dac4ef9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 874
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010dac5fdb -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010dcbcdd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d9a5ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    27  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112f44bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    28  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112f38440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    29  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112f382be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    30  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112ec6318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    31  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112ef33ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010d8d9d9b _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 206
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010e0e477c __handleEventQueue + 5672
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001100a3761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011008898c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110087e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110087884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011203ea6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    39  UIKit                               0x000000010d8e0c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  Photos 2                            0x000000010ce1f41f main + 111
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001110ae68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**Main.storyboard**
[Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogzs.png)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: *failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource*. Registering a cell in `cellForRow` and **after** using it is a bad idea anyway. And use **always** the passed table view instance in the delegate methods.

Comment: This will help you: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/fixing-failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource

Comment: I think perfect solution for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41566649/5514539

Comment: Dharmesh I already saw that, and this question actually uses that solution in the code, but thanks anyways. But Vivek it worked! Thank you!