# Is the launch image and opening animation causing my app to freeze?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to programming and was tasked with updating an iOS app that another company developed. The company used an animation to transition from the launch image to the main screen and, after updating the code to Swift 4 and fixing all the errors in the code, the app won't transition to the main view. After commenting out code I thought might be affecting it, and creating a new Xcode project to test if it was a problem was with the xib file, I'm at a loss as to what's wrong. While running the app in the simulator, it throws me this error in the AppDelegate file.

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

And this is what appears in the console at run time.

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/UITableView.m:9453
>   2018-08-30 14:12:04.456072-0600 Cabinet of Curiosities[5400:502120]
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView
>   (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0,
>   -20}; contentSize: {768, 1286}; adjustedContentInset: {20, 0, 0, 0}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource
>   ()'

I've been searching for a week trying to figure this out. And although I get the error in the AppDelegate file, I think the problems might be in the mainViewController file.

Comment: There should be some text associated with the exception in the console; please add that to your question. You can also set an exception breakpoint, but it appears you have an issue with a cell you are trying to show in a tableview

Comment: Also note - you *cannot* code anything into the launch screen. It's an image, a Storyboard, whatever. You have no access to the underlying view controller (if there is one). So the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @dfd I understand that. I think the problem might be with the code that plays the opening animation that makes it appear that the launch image transitions to the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the last line of the log you provided mentions :

> ```
> failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<Cabinet_of_Curiosities.CollectionViewController: 0x7f9c4540c5e0>)'
> ```

This looks more like a [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) issue to me : `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in `Cabinet_of_Curiosities .CollectionViewController` is probably returning an nil cell for some reason.

You can confirm that by putting a breakpoint in that method, on the `return` line.

For more details, you can check this answer by [TwoStraws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250654/1425697)