# UITableView failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know there have been a lot of questions on this subject but none of the answers are helping me so far.

I updated my xcode and suddenly there were a ton of errors so I clicked through and did the autofixes which usually work for me but somehow this time they broke my code. It was working perfectly until the update. Something went wrong in the following bit of code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "coinCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! GreekTableViewCell

    let cellPop = greekCoinArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.coinTitle.text = cellPop.title
    cell.tombstone.text = cellPop.tombstone
    cell.coinImage.image = UIImage(named: cellPop.obverse)
    cell.tombstone.numberOfLines = 0

    return cell
}
```

Is it obvious to anyone what is wrong? I am getting the error message:

> "Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]"..."Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView'... "failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<_UIFilteredDataSource:"

Comment: What did you auto fix exactly?

Comment: What version of Xcode and Swift are you using? Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is from Swift 2. It's pretty out of date.

Comment: This link would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250595/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource

Answer (score -1):

Have you set `cellIndentifier = "coinCell"` to your storyboard.

You can get reference from below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you are failing to dequeue a reusable cell.

1. First, check whether you have added the reuseIdentifier of cell in the storyboard
2. If you are using custom XIB file as a cell or you aren't using an Xcode template, then you have to register the cell using the following code

   ```
   self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CellName", bundle: nil),
                               forCellReuseIdentifier: "coinCell")
   ```
3. Make sure you have not forgotten to implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Protocols. eg:

   ```
   class viewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
   ```
4. Also, use latest datasource and delegate methods of UITableView