# failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource for swift4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4.2

What is wrong for below code:

```
// MARK: - TABLEVIEW DATA SOURCE
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return weeklyWeather.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") 
as! DailyWeatherTableViewCell

let dailyWeather = weeklyWeather[indexPath.row]
if let maxTemp = dailyWeather.maxTemperature {
  cell.temperatureLabel.text = "\(maxTemp)"
}
cell.weatherIcon.image = dailyWeather.icon
cell.dayLabel.text = dailyWeather.day

return cell
}
```

I was try to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols to the ViewController declaration.

and my DailyViewController:

```
class DailyViewController: UIViewController, 
 CLLocationManagerDelegate {
 // MARK: properties
 @IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var sunriseTimeLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var sunsetTimeLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var lowTemperatureLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var highTemperatureLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var precipitationLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var humidityLabel: UILabel!
```

and WeeklyTableViewController:

```
class WeeklyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - PROPERTIES
@IBOutlet weak var currentTemperatureLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherIcon: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var currentPrecipitationLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var currentTemperatureRangeLabel: UILabel?
```

but I'm getting failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

The entire exception is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView 
(<UITableView: 0x7fcfa7038600; frame = (0 0; 414 896); 
clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = 
<NSArray: 0x600003a31800>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003476ca0>; 
 contentOffset: {0, -88}; contentSize: {414, 684}; 
 adjustedContentInset: {88, 0, 34, 0}>) failed to obtain a cell 
 from its dataSource (<Rainy.WeeklyTableViewController: 
 0x7fcfa800c200>)'
```

Comment: This question has been already answered. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250595/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource

Comment: I look It, didnt help me.  Pls give me other suggestion

Comment: In which Controller you used tableview Delegate/Datasource methods.?

Comment: UITableViewController just

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you print weeklyWeather.count to see its number?

You may also peek the cell by setting a breakpoint at beginning of your tableView: cellForRowAt method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do that, It is 0 values

Comment: What number do you expect?

Comment: Do you expect zero here? Zero means no cell to show in the section.