# "UITableView failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource" with Multiple Custom cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have an NSArray (called masterArray) with 2 different type of objects in it - object1 and object2. These objects require 2 different table view cells (each one made programmatically), I implemented this as such

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[masterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[object1 class]])
    {
        cell1 *cell = (cell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"obj1Cell"];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[cell1 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"obj1Cell"];
        }
        //set up labels and stuff
        return cell;
    }

    if ([[masterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[object2 class]])
    {
        cell2 *cell = (cell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"obj2Cell"];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[cell2 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"obj2Cell"];
        }
        //set up labels and stuff
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now, this code displays the cells fine. When you tap a cell, I use this code:

```c
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    newViewController *newVC = [[newViewController alloc]init];
    newVC.item = [masterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
}
```

When I tap however, I get the error message "UITableView failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource". I've looked at other questions answering this too. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250595/failed-to-obtain-a-cell-from-its-datasource) says to add the line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

so I do so, replacing my "cell1 *cell = (cell1 *)..." line with

```
cell1 *cell = (cell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"obj1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

yet now I get a

```
"'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier obj1cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"
```

error, which doesn't apply in my situation because my UITableViewCells are made programmatically (there is no storyboard). Also recommended in that post is to add "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource", however this appears to only be an option in Swift, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Before using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with an ID, you need to register this ID like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = ...;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[cell1 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"obj1Cell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[cell2 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"obj2Cell"];
}
```

Additional notes:

- `if (cell == nil)` is redundant, because it is never nil in practice.
- In Objective-C the convention is to have class names started from an app prefix (2-3 uppercase letters), and an uppercase letter, e.g.: MYCell1, MYCell2, MYObject1, etc. (replace MY with something meaningful for you).

Comment: I added those lines, yet I'm still getting the same error... Thank you for the tip about the (cell == nil) line though. I never thought of it that way.

Comment: Are you sure all the objects in the array is either object1 class or object2 class?